# Trigger build with custom checkbox parameter

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-8.0

I am triggering a `Teamcity` build using the documentation at [Triggering a Custom Build](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP#AccessingServerbyHTTP-TriggeringaBuildFromScript)
The GET request I am submitting is

```
http://teamcity:80/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=TestRestBuildTrigger&agentId=36&name=TestCheckBox&value=false
```

However the value of the param `TestCheckBox` is passed as `true`.

`TestCheckBox` is a checkbox parameter with default value set to `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkbox works as follows:

- if you set any value, then it is considered as checked
- if you set no value `&value=`, then it is considered as unchecked

Also since TeamCity 8.1 the recommended way to trigger builds is via [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild).

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can't use REST API as I am using Teamcity 8.0.6